# vertical spacing around align* equations to match custom paragraph spacing

Tags: equations, lyx, paragraphs, vertical-spacing

**Context:** I find that I have to add custom vertical space between paragraphs using the Lyx gui.

**Problem:** Normal equations appear fine but multi-line align* equations have incorrect vertical spacing. These are the ones created using `cmd-shft-M`, then `cmd-enter`. See images below for examples.

**Details:** This is happening using the latest lyx 2.3.5 and latest mactex on the latest macOS. It happens with a new document with no other document setting applied other than the vertical custom paragraph spacing.

I always avoid using ERT and preamble, and try to stuck to the UI options only. I'd prefer a solution that does this, but would accept a solution that needs a preamble. ERT for every equation would be impractical in a 300-page book full of equations.

---

The following image attached show the effect. The spacing around the multi-line align* equation is too large. Around normal 1-line equations it is fine. This using a paragraph break between text and equations.

[image: test pdf output]

Some have advised me not to add a paragraph break between a text paragraph and display align *equation. This seems wrong in any case as a work around as there should be paragraph breaks between text and equations or image floats. The image shows the paragraph break removed from above the equation but not below.

[image: test image]

Comment: To whoever downvoted this question, please always leave constructive feedback, especially for newcomers. @Tariq welcome to tex.se! You put a lot of effort into your description of the issue, as well as screenshots. Thanks for doing that. Why do you think that there should be a paragraph break before display math? Usually the text describes the math, such as "we define a quadratic as follows:", followed by the math. In that case, isn't the math logically part of the paragraph?

Comment: I can't speak for lyx but the generated latex file should never have a paragraph break before display math, tex (at the primitive level) does not handle that at all well: it generates a spurious one line empty paragraph before the display.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle LyX allows a paragraph break if the user chooses to enter it. That is, just like LaTeX does not give an error if a user puts a paragraph before display math, LyX also does not give an error or prevent the user from doing it. Do you think it would be better for LyX to not allow a paragraph break before display math in any case? That is, is there any situation in which it might be desired?

Comment: @scottkosty it would be better if latex handled it better but it's tricky as tex really doesn't help. to a user it looks like vertical space but actually you get a one row paragraph with no text (so for example it's not dropped at a page break). It's probably safest to not change anything as a change will break some documents and there isn't a great alternative to change to. Lyx can blame latex and latex can blame tex and we can all sleep easily:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, David. That's good to know and sounds tricky indeed. I wonder if logging a warning would be appropriate. But even if it were appropriate, I don't think many users pay attention to warnings in the log so it wouldn't solve much. One possible action LyX could do would be to visibly mark the paragraph break in the LyX display so the user is at least aware there is an empty paragraph there.

Comment: thanks everyone for welcoming me to tex.se - and thanks for your comments.

Comment: My rationale is as follows. Each text paragraph is a block of related content. Lyx prevents you from adding two paragraph breaks between paragraphs - this is correct.  I also consider figure floats, table floats, and display equations to be "paragraphs" or similar blocks. As such they should be separated by a paragraph break. Several has suggested that display maths as an exception and should not have a paragraph break - in this case I am wrong but I feel this shouldn't be the convention. An inline equation has no paragraph break but a display equation does. ....

Comment: If there is no option but to avoid a page break before display maths, what is the correct method for increasing spacing above and below equations incl align* multiline equations in Lyx (ideally without ERT/preamble)?